# How to keep running a Thread after specific time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread which I wants to run after every 15 minute. Currently I am calling this thread from another class like

```
Class B{
public void start(){
 while(true){
 new Thread(new A()).start();
   }
 }
}

Class A implements Runnable{
  @override
  public void run(){
   //some operation
  }
}
```

How can I invoke Thread A on every 15 minute.

Comment: why not `sleep()` for 15 minutes?

Comment: I am not sure how to use that

Comment: You can't _call_ a thread.  You can _create_ a thread by creating a new Thread object, t, and then calling t.start().  You can't re-use a Thread object though:  You can call start() just once, and then if you want to do the same thing again, you have to create a new Thread object again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to repeat a task at an interval.

> An `ExecutorService` that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.

sample code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
}, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Find [more examples...](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html#executorservice-example)

Comment: Thank you I think I like it

Answer (score 3):

Look at classes [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

Answer (score 2):

use sleep like this:

```
public void run(){
  while(true){
  // some code
   try{
       Thread.sleep(15*60*1000) // sleep for 15 minutes
      }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

alternate options use class [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
Timer time = new Timer();
ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask();
time.schedule(st, 0, 15000);
```

or

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,long delay,long period);
```

Or even

`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` 's methods

```
schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

When started it can't start again.

You can put `Thread.Sleep(15*60*1000)` inside the `run` function in order to make it sleep and surround it with while in order to loop again.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `Timer` will do ya.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

  class A extends TimerTask {
     @Override
     public void run(){
        //some operation
     }
  }

  A task = new A();
  final long MINUTES = 1000 * 60;
  Timer timer = new Timer( true );
  timer.schedule(task, 15 * MINUTES, 15 * MINUTES);
```